# Max file size for File.ReadAllLines

Tags: vb.net, file

I need to read and process a text file. My processing would be easier if I could use the `File.ReadAllLines` method but I'm not sure what is the maximum size of the file that could be read with this method without reading by chunks.
I understand that the file size depends on the computer memory. But are still there any recommendations for an average machine?

Comment: I'm curious about this. What is the largest file size you've tried? How much memory do you have on your box? Have any exceptions been thrown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a maximum for the read in line of File.ReadLines()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738057/is-there-a-maximum-for-the-read-in-line-of-file-readlines)

Answer (score 1):

On a 32-bit operating system, you'll get at most a contiguous chunk of memory around 550 Megabytes, allowing loading a file of half that size.  That goes down hill quickly after your program has been running for a while and the virtual memory address space gets fragmented.  100 Megabytes is about all you can hope for.

This is not an issue on a 64-bit operating system.

Since reading a text file one line at a time is just as fast as reading all lines, this should never be a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've done stuff like this with 1-2GB before, albeit in Python. I do not think .NET would have a problem, though. But I would only do this for one-off processing.

If you are doing this on a regular basis, you might want to go through the file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Its bad design unless you know the files sizes vs the computer memory that would be avaiable in the running app.

A better solution would be consider [memory mapped files](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=+memory+mapped+files+.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a). They use themselvses as page fil storage,