# Is there a maximum for the read in line of File.ReadLines()?

Tags: c#, readlines

What happen if the file has very-long line(s)?

Is there any limitation to how long a line is to iterate each of

```
File.ReadLines()
```

Comment: I would imagine the documentation would list any limitations...

Comment: No, other than the 2GB CLR object size limitation.

Comment: have you had a look at the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Since the documentation doesn't say anything about the limit of a line read from a file, the limit then becomes that of a regular `string`.

A string, whose length is given by a signed int, can have up to 2^31 characters (2,147,483,647).

However, since objects are also capped at 2GB, 2^31 characters is not the actual limit. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), you can fit about 1 billion characters in those 2GB.

Answer (score 3):

I did not see any info regarding maximum length for [File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx). I would imagine the only limitation is that a string can't exceed 2GB, which is roughly 1 billion characters. That was listed on the MSDN page for [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx).